# Incorrect partition Centos 7, out of space on cl-root

Tags: raid, centos7, partition

Running Centos 7 on Cisco UCS server with 16TB of Raid hard drives. I'm at 99% of space on cl-root partition. I must have incorrectly partitioned the space initially.  How can I increase /dev/mapper/cl-root using some of the space in /dev/mapper/cl-home without having to redo the entire thing?

Here's some pics:

[KDiskFree -showing disk usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHoy7.jpg)

[lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXqcZ.jpg)

I appreciate any help.
Paul

Comment: My guess is that you have some old and very large log files in /var/log. Can you check to see if there are logs that can be removed? 50GB should be plenty. Are you running virtual machines using KVM/qemu?

Comment: @Gordster Thanks I will check the logs. I'm not running any VM's.

Comment: @Gordster nothing in the logs stands out as particularly big.  I use this server to record 8 ip security cameras.  Its alot of hard disk writing but not much else.  The program I use is called Xemoa.  My only guess is that every time I add a camera it uses up a certain amount of space.

Comment: @Gordster you gave me a good idea to look for why this partition was filling up.  I used a program called Baobab and it showed me a topographical overviw of what was filling up the drive.  It looks like a few years ago Xeoma was initially writing security cam footage to this partition incorrectly but I must have fixed it but never deleted the footage.  Thanks for giving me some sanity while I figured this out!!!

Answer (score 0):

50GB should be plenty for the / partition.

My guess is that there are old log files that are growing extremely large and may need to be rotated with `logrotate`.

Also- if you are running virtual machines with KVM/QEMU then the VMs may be getting stored at /var/lib/libvirt/images, which needs to be moved to a different partition.